# Access data in an object

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to access a data in an object, but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried with

```
myObj.weather["humidity"];
```

and

```
myObj.weather[1];
```

I am tring to acces for example the humidity from the json "82" but i getting "undefined"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Creating an Object from a Object Literal</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const myObj = {"code":200,"weather":[{"feels_like":21.48,"humidity":82,"pressure":1011,"temp":21.17,"temp_max":23.47,"temp_min":19.55}]};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.weather["humidity"];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: _"Describe the problem. **"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough** to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_ (Source: [mcve])

Comment: `myObj.weather` is an array

Comment: `myObj["weather"][0]["humidity"]`

Comment: Thank you both. The answer is myObj["weather"][0]["humidity"] thank you @AhsanKhan :D